# Discord JS Bot - How to create a vulgarism filter ?

Tags: discord.js

and is if it's possible, can the bot react to only one person's vulgarisms?
I want to do a joke to my friend xD

Comment: Way to broad of an request. Have you tried google yet?

Answer (score 0):

## A vulgarism filter

Create a file named `bad-words.txt`. Then put some bad words there.

I'll gonna use `foo`, `bar` instead because of StackOverflow.

```
foo, bar, baz, t-series
```

Suppose, a text is posted which says: `foo bar is shit`.

Install a module using **npm**: `npm i bad-words`.

```js
const BadWords = require('bad-words');
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');

// Matches both ("foo,bar" and "foo, bar")
const bwo_list = readFileSync('bad-words.txt').split(/, ?/);
const bwo_filter = BadWords({ list: bwo_list });


bot.on('message', message => {
    // Checks for profrane words!
    if(bwo_filter.isProfane(message.content))
        message.delete();
});
```

> Thanks for reading this I hope that helps :)
>   
>   Read the [API documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bad-words).